# I want to cut the first and last data of the array

Tags: arrays, json

I want to cut the first and last part of the arrangement.

What should I do?

When you take a picture of the data, it comes out as follows.

```
console.log("res===>>" + JSON.stringify(res))
```

res===>> [{......}]

I want the data to come out like this.
'['   , ']'

res===>>{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the received data to the format.

```
for (var d in res) {
     var item = res[d];
     vm.data.addChildren(item)
     vm.treeData.push(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you just do ...

> console.log("res===>>" + JSON.stringify(res[0]))

but if it returns more them one item at the array it will show only the first one in your console.log.

Cheers

Comment: So what do we do about it? more them one item

Comment: you can do this ... <script>res.forEach(function(i) { console.log(i);});</script> This way all layers of the array will be logged.
Cheers!